# Custom Scroll Control for PageView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a `PageView` with a vertical scroll direction, and I want to have custom scroll control over it. By default, the `PageView` switches to the next page when the current page is scrolled up to `50%`, but I want it to change pages when the page is scrolled up to `25%`. To achieve this, I implemented the following code in my widget's `initState`.

```
final PageController _pageController = PageController();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _pageController.addListener(() {
    double pageScrolled = _pageController.page! - _pageController.page!.floor();

    if (pageScrolled > 0.25) {
      _pageController.nextPage(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
      );
    }
    if (pageScrolled < -0.25) {
      _pageController.nextPage(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
      );
    }
  });
}
```

However, I'm encountering two problems with this implementation:

**1. When I scroll downwards, it goes all the way to the bottom and does
not stop on the next page.**

**2. After reaching the last page, it does not return to the previous
page even after scrolling 100%. It gets returned to the bottom page
automatically.**